# Add label to formatted billing phone and email on WooCommerce thankyou

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add custom label to phone and email information on 'Thank You' page. With YITH WooCommerce Checkout Manager I customized some fields and added the following code to functions.php:

```
function woo_custom_order_formatted_billing_address( $address , $WC_Order ) {
$address = array(
            'first_name' => 'First Name: ' . $WC_Order->billing_first_name,
            'address_1'  => 'Address: ' . $WC_Order->billing_address_1,
            'city'      => 'City: ' . $WC_Order->billing_city,
        );

        if(!empty($ship_date)) $address['order_time'] = 'Shipping time: ' . $ship_date;
        if(!empty($WC_Order->billing_corpus)) $address['house'] = 'House: ' . $WC_Order->billing_house;
        if(!empty($WC_Order->billing_corpus)) $address['corpus'] = 'Corpus: ' . $WC_Order->billing_corpus;
        if(!empty($WC_Order->billing_flat)) $address['flat'] = 'Room: ' . $WC_Order->billing_flat;
            if(!empty($WC_Order->billing_phone)) $address['billing_phone'] = 'Phone: ' . $WC_Order->billing_phone;

        return $address;
}
```

But for some reason label 'Phone' doesn't want to be added.

[image: Result]

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For that you can do it using 2 different ways:

**1). [Overriding WooCommerce templates via your theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)**

You will have to copy/edit [`order/order-details-customer.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/order/order-details-customer.php#L37) template file as the billing phone and the billing email are not handled by the billing formatted address function.

**For the Billing Phone** you need to replace the line **`37`**:

```
<p class="woocommerce-customer-details--phone"><?php echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_phone() ); ?></p>
```

by the following line:

```
<p class="woocommerce-customer-details--phone"><?php _e("Phone: ", "woocommerce"); echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_phone() ); ?></p>
```

**For the Billing email** you need to replace the line **`41`**:

```
<p class="woocommerce-customer-details--email"><?php echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_email() ); ?></p>
```

by the following line:

```
<p class="woocommerce-customer-details--email"><?php _e("Email: ", "woocommerce"); echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_email() ); ?></p>
```

---

**2). Using some composite filter hooks** *(for Order Received - Thankyou page)*

```
// Phone
add_filter('woocommerce_order_get_billing_phone', 'wc_order_get_billing_phone_filter' );
function wc_order_get_billing_phone_filter( $billing_phone ) {
    // Only on Order Received page (thankyou)
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) && $billing_phone ) {
        return __("Phone:", "woocommerce") . ' ' . $billing_phone;
    }
    return $billing_phone;
}

// Email
add_filter('woocommerce_order_get_billing_email', 'wc_order_get_billing_email_filter' );
function wc_order_get_billing_email_filter( $billing_email ) {
    // Only on Order Received page (thankyou)
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) && $billing_email ) {
        return __("Email:", "woocommerce") . ' ' . $billing_email;
    }
    return $billing_email;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thx. 1 method is more preferable, cause 2 method also returns lables for overview div.